# Multithreading in node.js with express

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
      const allRes=[];
      const numberOfFiles = req.files.file.length;
      for(let i=0;i<numberOfFiles;i++){
        const ret = await faceApiService.detect(req.files.file[i]);
        allRes.push(ret);
      }
      
      res.json({
        my: allRes,
      });
    
    });
```

Hi, I have this code in my express project that get ad array of images and detect the faces in every photo and save in a file a new image with a box that identify the face. This code need 1sec for every image. I'd like to add a multithread for divide my array of images in 2 threads, how i can do it?

Comment: @jfriend00 run locally. it is a .js file in my express project

Comment: Then if everything is run locally, you'd have to create N child processes, create a job queue (which can just be an array) and create a system for sending jobs to each child process and when they send the results back, you send them another job.  There are some libraries that help you do some of this - you'd have to find them on NPM.

Comment: What library are you using for the face recognition?

Comment: I have follow this tutorial: https://dev.to/kvntzn/using-face-api-in-nodejs-38aj

Comment: can you make a simple example how to use job queue in my project? I can't get it to work

Comment: Why don't you show your code you have so far and explain where you got stuck.